# Does there exist a positive irrational number $\alpha $, such that for any positive integer $n$ the number $\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor$ is not a prime?

Tags: number-theory

Does there exist a positive irrational number $\alpha $, such that for any positive integer $n$ the number $\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor$ is not a prime? 
My try if $\alpha=\sqrt{17}$ then $\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor=4n$

Comment: That try will fail: $\lfloor 9\sqrt{17} \rfloor=37$

Comment: $\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor$ is definitely not expressible in the form $cn$ when $\alpha$ is irrational.

Comment: you can express finite sub-sequences of $x_n = \lfloor n \alpha \rfloor$ as $y_n = c n+d$, I think all the point is to prove that some of those have $gcd(c,d ) = 1$, and that they are large enough for applying the [Dirichlet theorem in arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

Answer (score 7):

This is called  a Beatty sequence.  [Here](https://www.arxiv.org/pdf/1512.08382.pdf) is an arxiv paper on the least prime in a Beatty sequence, by Steuding and Technau.  There will indeed always be a prime in the sequence (which answers the original question), and the cited paper gives an upper bound for the least such prime for $\alpha>1$.  The bound for the OP's sequence (provided $\alpha>1$) is $$p\le L^{35-16\epsilon}\alpha^{2(1-\epsilon)}p^{1+\epsilon}_{m+l}$$

where $L=\log(2\alpha)$, $p_n$ denotes the numerator of the $n^\text{th}$ convergent to the regular continued fraction expansion of $\alpha$, and $m$ is the unique integer such that $p_m\le L^{16}\alpha^2<p_{m+1}$.  $\epsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily small, but $l$ depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: one of  the main trick is at the beginning of page 3 : "This means that the proportion of fractional
parts $\{\alpha p\} = \alpha p − \lfloor \alpha p\rfloor$ which fall in an interval $[a, b) \subset [0, 1)$ is equal
to $b − a$ (the length of the interval) " and from there can we apply the Dirichlet theorem on arithmetic progressions ?  there is also, just before " the sequence of
numbers $\alpha p$, where $p$ runs through the prime numbers in ascending order, is uniformly distributed modulo one"

Comment: I found this for a more succinct explanation http://xvienemsalamanca.anemat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/On-the-Least-Prime-Number-in-a-Beatty-Sequence.pdf