# Does there exist a positive irrational number $\alpha$, the number $\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor$ is never a prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, irrational-numbers

Does there exist a positive irrational number $\alpha,$ such that for any positive integer $n$ the number $\lfloor n\alpha  \rfloor$ is not a prime?

Comment: I don't have the solution, but it feels wrong to me and I have a reformulation to try to show that.  Let $\alpha = k + \beta$, with $k\in\mathbb N$ and $0<\beta<1$.  Then $\lfloor n\alpha\rfloor=kn+\lfloor k\beta\rfloor$.  Since $0<\beta<1$, for each $m\in\mathbb N$, there is a $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $m=\lfloor n\alpha\rfloor$.  The reformulation to try to prove it wrong, is : given $k$, is there a $n$ such that $kn + 1$ is prime ?

Comment: $\lfloor n\alpha\rfloor$ is a prime number with a probability close to $\frac{1}{\log n}$ and $\prod_{n\geq 2}\left(1-\frac{1}{\log n}\right)=0$, hence by the Borel-Cantelli lemma I am expecting that such peculiar irrational numbers have measure zero.

Comment: Clearly there are no such $\alpha$ in $[0,4]$.  Checking some but not all primes below $10^5$, there are no such $\alpha$ in $[4.00004,6]$ or in $[6.00006,8]$ and it seems implausible that there might be any small $\alpha$ with this property

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498576/primes-in-lfloor-an-rfloor?rq=1

Comment: Your question seems to be answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812785/does-there-exist-a-positive-irrational-number-alpha-such-that-for-any-posit?rq=1